# escape characters - whats for

Tags: c#, c++, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Would love to get answers and a practical examples of the functionality of the following examples:

```
string str =" my \v question ";
```

And with these escape signs:

- `\0`
- `\r`
- `\f`

Comment: None of those are valid escape strings. did you mean `\v`, `\0`, `\r`, and `\f`?

Comment: How would you go about putting a newline into your text without considerably more effort if escape characters didn't exist?

Comment: What functionality are you referring to? How to use escape characters in strings?? Just use the @ symbol to keep things literal in strings. `string str = @"my \ v question"`

Comment: @chris Newline would just be annoying, characters like the null character or backspace just couldn't be done.

Comment: @Servy, I meant you can put in the integer equivalents (at least in C++), like 0 for \0. It's still very annoying compared to using these, though.

Answer (score 5):

These are a list of acceptable sequence character.

```
Escape Sequence Character
\a  Bell (beep)
\b  Backspace
\f  Formfeed
\n  Newline
\r  Return
\t  Tab
\\  Backslash
\'  Single quote
\"  Double quote
\xdd    Hexadecimal representation
```

http://www.gillius.org/ctut/app_a.htm

Comment: Trivia:  While most people conceptualize `\0` as an escape-sequence for nil, its really a short-version 3-digit Octal. Example: `\101` = Decimal 65 = Ascii "A".   `\0` == `\000` == nil/Zero

Comment: Note that some of these are archaic and won't do much on a modern system. I don't think the Bell character has beeped since DOS, and is there anything that responds to Formfeed beyond a dot-matrix printer?

Comment: @MarkRansom: `less` understands form feeds, producing correctly "paged" output.

Comment: thanks ,  but what about \v ? when i need to use it ?
can u give me an example using \f ?

Comment: @user1596023 There is no such thing.